# Initializing class attribute using a method

Tags: ruby

The goal is to initialize a class attribute using a class method that's overridden in sub-classes. Following is the definition of my ruby classes:

```
class A
  class_attribute :query
  self.query = self.generate_query

  def self.generate_query
     return "abcd"
  end
end

class B  < A
  def self.generate_query
     query_part_1 = "ab"
     return query_part_1 + generate_query_part_2
  end

  def self.generate_query_part_2
    return part_2
  end
end
```

The reason I want to do this is because `query` is a constant string per class and should not be created again on instantiation but it's a complex string which is generated in multiple independent parts. Separating this logic out in methods would make the code cleaner. However, with this code, I get the `undefined method generate_query for class A`.

I have tried lazy initialization of the class attribute while instantiating the class like the following:

```
def initialize
  query = self.class.get_query
end

def self.get_query
    self.query = self.generate_query if self.query.nil?
end
```

However, this initializes the query to same value for both class A and B if A is instantiated first because `self.query.nil?` would then return false for B also.

Comment: "However, with this code, I get the undefined method generate_query for class A." – Hint: what line do you call it on? What line do you define it on? Which of the two comes first?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks! I did realize that myself that the error is due to the ordering. However, just changing the ordering would not give desired behavior in case of sub-classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is simple:

You are calling `self.query = self.generate_query` before your `generate_query` method has been defined! Remember - Ruby is interpreted top to bottom and your class body is no different. You cannot call a method before it is defined.
Simply changing the code around to

```
class A
  class_attribute :query

  def self.generate_query
    return "abcd"
  end

  self.query = self.generate_query
end
```

will make it work, but then you will have another problem, as the line `self.query = self.generate_query` will only get evaluated once in your class - `B` will reference the `"abcd"` query, not `"ab2"`.

To achieve the behavior you want - you need to define a getter method yourself which acts as an attribute (`class_attribute` does the same thing under the hood btw)

### Solution

```
class A
  def self.query
    @query ||= self.generate_query
  end

  def self.generate_query
    return "abcd"
  end
end

class B  < A
  def self.generate_query
    query_part_1 = "ab"
    return query_part_1 + generate_query_part_2
  end

  def self.generate_query_part_2
    return '2'
  end
end
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of making `query` a class attribute. What this means is that `generate_query` will be called and a new string constructed every time a new instance of the class is created.

Comment: No, `generate_query` will be called only if `@query` is nil. `@query` is a class attribute and will stay defined on the `A`/`B` object forever - try it yourself by adding a `puts` statement in `generate_query`

Comment: Ah..my mistake. Thanks for your answer, this works perfectly.